# Late binding not working with FlatFileItemReader

Tags: java, spring-batch, late-binding

```
`JdbcStepExecutionDao:275 - Truncating long message before update of StepExecution, original message is: org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.open(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.open(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
at (...)myBaseJob.executeInternal(BaseJob.java:49)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input resource must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:245)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144)
    ... 41 more`

I have two step. In the first step i create a file and pass file to reader (as a resource) with name INPUT_FILENAME using the following code:

```
JobExecution jobExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution();
ExecutionContext executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
String filePath = "file://" + FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(mydFile.getAbsolutePath());
executionContext.put("INPUT_FILENAME", filePath);



<batch:job id="transformJob" job-repository="jobRepository">

    <batch:step id="step1" next=step2"> 
        <batch:tasklet ref="step1Tasklet" />
         <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="promotionInputFileNameListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="imTransactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="step2Reader" writer="step2Writer" commit-interval="${step2.interval}" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

```
 <bean id="promotionInputFileNameListener" class="org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <property name="keys" value="INPUT_FILENAME"/>
</bean>

<bean id="step1Tasklet" class="com.ProduceFileTasklet" scope="step"/>

<bean id="step2Reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters[INPUT_FILENAME]}" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="..." />
                    <property name="columns" value="..." />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.myClass" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The StepContext of step2 is never auto refreshed by promoter.

Answer (score 0):

I see step 2 is looking for the input file from #jobParameters, but in the code snippet it is set on the execution context not a parameter.  So instead it looks like it should look for the file name in #jobExecutionContext.